# Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\wamp\www\Test-CI\application\views\layout.php on line 5

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP, I am trying to setup it for the firs time, but it give the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in
>
> 1. C:\wamp\www\Test-CI\application\views\layout.php on line 5
> 2. {main}( ) IN ..\index.php:0 require_once('C:\wamp\www\Test-CI\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' ) IN ..\index.php:202
> 3. call_user_func_array ( ) IN ..\CodeIgniter.php:359
> 4. Home->index( ) IN ..\CodeIgniter.php:0
> 5. CI_Loader->view( ) IN ..\home.php:17
> 6. CI_Loader->_ci_load( ) IN ..\Loader.php:419
> 7. include('C:\wamp\www\Test-CI\application\views\layout.php' ) IN ..\Loader.php:833

My code :

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Galleriffic | Custom layout with external controls</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/css/basic.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/css/galleriffic-5.css" type="text/css" />
        
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/css/white.css" type="text/css" /> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/css/black.css" type="text/css" />
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.history.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
        <!-- We only want the thunbnails to display when javascript is disabled -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<style>.noscript { display: none; }</style>');
        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: You need URL helper .. refer http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: possible duplicate of [base\_url() function not working in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 176):

You have to load the [url](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) helper to access that function.
Either you add

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

somewhere in your controller.

Alternately, to have it be loaded automatically everywhere, make sure the line in [application/config/autoload.php](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) that looks like

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

has `'url'` in that array (as shown above).

Comment: this works perfectly, was having issues generating link with base_url for my anchor tag

Answer (score 20):

just add

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

in autoload.php in your config file

Comment: I personally would discourage using autoload for new users ... it is better to do it manually over and over again (as with everything) to learn it solidly AND THEN you can start using shortcuts ... just my opinion ...

Answer (score 12):

You need to load the helper before loading the view somewhere in your controller.

But I think here you want to use the function `site_url()`

Before you load your view, basically anywhere inside the method in your controller, add this to your code :

`$this->load->helper('url');`

Then use the function  `site_url()`.

Answer (score 6):

There is only three way to solve.
paste in following code in this path application/config/autoload.php.

most of them I use this

```
require_once BASEPATH . '/helpers/url_helper.php';
```

this is good but some time, it fail

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

I never use it but I know it work

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Answer (score 5):

To load other file(css ,js) and folder(images) , in codeigniter project

we have to follow two simple step:

1.create folder public (can give any name) in your codeigniters folder put your bootstrap files css and js folder in side public folder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2gr6.jpg

2.now we have to use two line of code 
         1.load->helper('url'); ?>
         2.

go to your view file

put first line to load base URL

```
   <?php $this->load->helper('url'); ?>
```

secondly in your html head tag put this

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/public/css/bootstrap.css">
```

now you can enjoy the bootstrap in your codeigniter

Answer (score 4):

you have to use `echo` before `base_url()` function. otherwise it woudn't print the base url.

Answer (score 4):

Go to application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

add this on top anywhere

and at this in controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('url');

}
```

Answer (score 3):

codeigniter needs to load the url helper to call the `base_url()` function.

use `application->config->autoload.php`

edit autoload helper array and add url helper..

`base_url()` function is working now..

Answer (score 1):

first you have to give echo to display base url. Then change below value in your autoload.php which will be inside your application/config/ folder.
        `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
then your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are extending `CI_Controller` class in your controller and in the view you have to `echo base_url($path)` function, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` to `autoload.php`.

Comment: @kenorb Yes it does provide an answer. It's even the correct one. Unfortunately the question is also a duplicate.

Comment: @holodoc It could be, but the answer was copied from other up-voted answers, so it should be removed anyway. There are already too many the exact same answers which was posted later on. So either people doesn't read other answers, or they think they could gain some points.

Comment: @kenorb Copied or not its still a valid answer. Voting habits of the community are a completely different topic. Either way, question is flagged as duplicate now, will probably get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable as `$base_url`

```
$base_url = load_class('Config')->config['base_url'];

<?php echo $base_url ?>
```

and call it in your code..

Answer (score 0):

..

here i set value of href is the path of file you get this path by following step

search localhost on browser then go in directory where file saved & then copy url

note* ** if you have any index.php or index.html or other index named file change the name temporary for get url then after you undo file name **

*use this not need use function*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<link href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/css/sm_reg.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

here i set value of href is the path of file you get this path by following step

search localhost on browser then go in directory where file saved & then copy url

note* ** if you have any index.php or index.html or other index named file change the name temporary for get url then after you undo file name **

*use this not need use function*