# Codeigniter: css is not working and is eating my code

Tags: css, codeigniter

I just set up new CI but css is not working and it is eating my code.

This is my only view, i looked in the source code and found code after `<head>` is disappearing when i put the  css link tag.

```
<! DOCTYPE html !>
<html>
 <head>
   <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="container">
       <h1>Workforce</h1>  

       <?php 
       foreach($results as $r){
          echo $r->name.'<br>'; 
       }    
       ?>

    </div>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know CI, but I just had to look at your question with that great title. I don't think the css actually ate the code. You should turn on error reporting in php.ini for development (Google should be able to help you with this). It's much easier to debug this kind of thing when you can see the errors.

Comment: I think this following link should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter Question is: did you search?