# Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter

This line keeps giving me the aforementioned error:

```
<img style="padding:10px; margin:auto; display:block;" <?php echo 'src="' . base_url("assets/images/email/mailheader.jpg") . '"' ?>>
```

I'm running this on xampp and can't seem to figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you defined a `base_url()` function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter

Comment: Yes, $autoload['helper'] = array('common_functions', 'form', 'url'); is present in autoload.php and the function works when called from other view files, just not this one for some reason.

Comment: how is this view different than the other views? can you post the code from one where it works? are there different controllers?

Answer (score 4):

You need to load the URL helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('common_functions', 'form', 'url'); is already present in autoload.php

Comment: Can you also include the code I added, at the beginning of the view?

Comment: doing so results in     Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: are you using it in a helper function? probably you have not extended the codeigniter controller... Use $CI = get_instance();
For older versions of php, use =&
Then, use $CI wherever you would normally use $this

Answer (score 3):

You need to write

```
 public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

In your controller and then use  in your view