# CodeIgniter base_url() not working in 000webhost.com

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just uploaded a web project using PHP Codeigniter in 000webhost.com and works fine.

But there is a problem though. The function base_url() is not working.

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by isn't working? Is there an error?

Comment: When you echo it out , what prints out?

Comment: (Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in /home/a9056225/public_html/Dota2Quiz/application/views/main_page_v.php on line 20) That is the error. Help guys

Comment: Have you loaded the [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)?

Comment: yes. In the config/autoload.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [base\_url() function not working in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the `url helper` in your controller

```
$this->load->helper('url')
```

Another better way is to `autoload` the helper.
For this edit your `config/autoload.php`.

Comment: u need the exact line ?