# stylesheet is loading but style is not applying for admin panel of codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, admin

Stylesheet is loading for codeigniter adminpanel.

But my style css file is not applying for adminpanel.
I have added stylesheet as follows and the adminpanel url is `http://www.xyz.com/demo/admin.`

```
<link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/uploadify.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449396/1730805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->config->set_item('base_url', 'http://www.xyz.com/demo/admin');

<link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/uploadify.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
```

Comment: i can view my stylesheet when i click the link from souce in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load url helper to use url function

```
$this->load->helper('url');


<link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/uploadify.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
```