# '---addressing CSS in CodeInteger

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I want load a css file to my page. This my code for load css:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/emdad.css" />`

Also, I set  this code in my controller:
`$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','html'));`

Really, I am very confused. In this I write piece of my code.

Controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
           $this->load->library('emdadlib');
           $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','html'));
    }

    public function index(){

        $this->load->view('structure',$data);
    }

    public function register(){

          $this->load->view('structure',$data);
    }
```

this is view(structure.php):

```
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/emdad.css" />
```

base_url is: `127.0.0.1/emdad`. I type `127.0.0.1/emdad/index.php/main/register` in url browser. then page is loaded successfully but the css file does not handle.

Comment: So what is the problem? Does your link work or not?

Comment: add code in view <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/emdad.css" /> means your emdad.css on root/css dir?

Comment: I add the code in view. directory css is  in my root directory(www). also the link work correctly. the view page is loading successfully but css does not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base_url()` refers to the main website folder, for example `c:\www\yourWebsite\app` .

Edit: This is true if your config file has `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Try changing the link to your css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/emdad.css" />
```

Also, try debugging the view in chrome using the inspector (ctrl+i) and see if there are any information or errors in the `console` .
If there are - please post them here.

Also - look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter/6449396#6449396)

Comment: I try your suggest, but I have problem still.If I type in url browser "127.0.0.1/emdad" and set `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/emdad.css" />` in view,then , the css file is handled successfully!!! but the abov case that do nor working.

Comment: Well my suggestion is using a standard CI folder structure.
Try debugging the base_url() - just echo it to the view and see where it points too. What doest the chrome inspector console say ?

Comment: your suggest is correct, I solve my problem, thanks a lot wicj3d, you help me.

Comment: @Javad I'm glad I could help - don't forget to accept my anwser if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use your css in layout folder which is in

```
../application/views/layout/
```

and when you calling loader you can add in `controller` file