# what is the difference between codeigniter controller & controller/?

Tags: css, codeigniter, url

when I load the url:

```
http://icetopup.tk/secure/login
```

it works. but when I load:

```
http://icetopup.tk/secure/login/
```

it shows page content but without css. anybody know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have relative paths to your CSS files in your template. The two paths will work the same in CodeIgniter, but they have a very different meaning from the browser's perspective:

`http://icetopup.tk/secure/login` means: the resource 'login' in the directory 'secure', so '/secure/' is the offset directory for relative paths.

`http://icetopup.tk/secure/login/` means: the default document from the directory 'login', so '/secure/login/' is the offset directory for relative paths.

To solve this, make sure to use the `base_url()` function:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>/css/yourfile.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('css/yourfile.css')?>">
```

This function is in the URL helper file, so you'll need to load that, if you didn't do so already.

See also:

- [CodeIgniter User Guide: URL Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) - official docs
- [base_url() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter) - related question

Comment: Thanks. there was a js file init.js, that was re declaring css paths.