# Problems with echo base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have already loaded the URL helper, I have set the base url in config, yet this code seems to gave me:

```
PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Filename: views/site_navigation.php

Line Number: 6
```

Here is line number six:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/welcome">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: @tanaydin it's a CodeIgniter function - possibly a more relevant duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter

Comment: Can you show your config file and your URL helper in the controller? From what I'm seeing looks good, but there could be something you missed causing it to error out.

Comment: And how could you loaded the helper?!

Comment: just add url helper in auto load

Answer (score 5):

This *error* means **only one** thing that you did not load the [**url helper**](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/url_helper.html) correctly. Please follow the documentation and [**load it**](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/helpers.html) as specified from your current action or from the constructor of your controller.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to use the `base_url();` or `config_item('base_url')` or `$this->config->item('base_url')`

**First example:**

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

**Or**

```
public function index() {
   $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

**Second Example:**

Go to **application / config / autoload.php**

And add the url to here which I think is best for you.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array(
    'url',
    'file',
    'form',
    'text',
    'html',
    'date'
);
```

Now go to the **application / config / config.php** Find `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Enter your base url example `http://www.example.com/` or `http://localhost/project/`

- `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';` Recommended include forward slash at end
- `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';` Recommended include forward slash at end

If you need to remove the index.php find htaccess examples here

[Download htaccess for codeigniter Git hub](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Codeigniter User Guides

[Codeigniter User Guides For Version 2 & 3 Can Be Found Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs)

**Once all that is done**

`<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>`

**This will get you to the default home page**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **CI 2.0.0** (in line number 67)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or else if you are using **CI 3.0.0** (in line number 91)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**in addition**

Assign these empty

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

base_url() is a function of the object config
Try this: `<li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>/welcome">Home</a></li>`

Comment: This no longer gives me an error, however now when i click the links, it directs me to "this webpage is not available", I have checked the page source and the URL's in the links are as they should be.

Comment: Make sure that the site_url variable in the config.php file is setted properly and then use $this->config->site_url();

Comment: there is no variable in the config.php file for site url?

Comment: shall i paste '$this->config->site_url(); ' into the config.php file or in the view?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Verify the $config['base_url'] variable

Comment: Paste it in the view
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->config->site_url(); ?>/welcome">Home</a></li>

Comment: This brings up the right url in the address bar, however it still comes up with This web page is not available

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: whereas if i just type the url without navigating through the link, the page works fine

Answer (score 0):

Check your

> CI/system/helpers/url_helper.php

```
function base_url($uri = '', $protocol = NULL)
{
    return get_instance()->config->base_url($uri, $protocol);
}
```

you can set it on

> CI/application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php `$config['base_url']= "localhost/meusite` to open Autoload `library('url')` or controller `$this->load->library('url')`.