# Jquery Ajax - no success getting error

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Could someone figure out why every ajax call is leading to error. Here goes my problem.
[image]

The code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#officer-id').change(function(){
    var officer_id = $('#officer-id').val();
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:"<?=base_url()?>" + "Home/ajax_view",
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{'officer_id':officer_id},
      success:function(data){
                   alert(this.data ); 
       },
      error:function(data){
                alert("error");
      }


    });
});
});
```

the Id officer_id  in the html code is

```
   <select id="officer-id" placeholder="Choose an officer">
               <option value=ab1>ab1</option><option value=ab2>ab2</option><option value=rep1>rep1</option>
            </select>
```

the `url:"<?=base_url()?>" + "Home/ajax_view"`  content

```
  public function ajax_view(){
    return ;
  }
```

**Why my code is not executing success inspite of getting no error in console**

Comment: Could you post the actual generated HTML code? Maybe the URL is not being composed properly.

Comment: I have edited the code with actual generated html

Comment: We need the JavaScript as well...

Comment: No javascript is used.. i have only used jquery which i posted

Comment: I assume this is codeigniter?  this looks similar to your issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter

Comment: Err... "No Javascript is used"?? jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: Are you just returning nothing in `ajax_view()`?

Comment: it is working base_url()  i am getting the reponse too . if you wanna see i have edited the ajax_view controller http://pastebin.com/96JwwGN0 and now it is not empty and i am getting output  http://picpaste.com/response-Dy1mNuXR.png

Comment: I was returning nothing in ajax_view() server side because i was trying to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success

Comment: What is the error in message `console.log(arguments);`

Comment: getting  
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#officer-id').change(function(){
    var officer_id;
    if(officer_id = $(this).val()){ //
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:"http://62.231.118.52:9080/teste/random_test/form_validate.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          data:{'officer_id':officer_id},
          success:function(data){
                       alert(this.data ); 
           },
          error:function(data){
                    alert("error");
          }


        });
    }
});
```