# How do I access site url or base url from codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to access my site url or base url from my controller in codeigniter 3. I tried `$this->url->site_url()` and `$this->config->site_url()`. None worked. Is it even possible?

Comment: Please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter or you could simply call `echo base_url();`

Comment: simply echo `site_url()` or `base_url()` ....!

Comment: Also note if you are using CI3 and up it is now recommend that you set your base url in the config.php

Comment: Okay, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `URL Helper` and function `site_url()`

This helper is loaded using the following code:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
echo site_url();
```

---

```
site_url()
```

> Returns your site URL, as specified in your config file. The index.php
>   file (or whatever you have set as your site index_page in your config
>   file) will be added to the URL, as will any URI segments you pass to
>   the function, and the url_suffix as set in your config file.
>
> You are encouraged to use this function any time you need to generate
>   a local URL so that your pages become more portable in the event your
>   URL changes.
>
> Segments can be **optionally passed** to the function as a string or an
>   array. Here is a string example:
>
> ```
> echo site_url("news/local/123");
> ```
>
> The above example would return something like:
>   http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123