# base_url() returns wrong value

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.0 which latest now. I have set `base_url` in config.php as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/kp_clients/';
```

When I print `base_url()`. It is showing Server IP instead what I set.

```
http://173.x.xx.21/kp_clients/
```

Now what I am doing wrong here. Any idea?

I have autoloaded all required library

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**and its working fine in local but stoppped working in live server**

NOTE: [base_url() function not working in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)
I have checked this. This is because not load `url` helper. I have clearly mentioned in my question that I have autoloaded the helper. Still its showing IP instead what I am setting

Comment: @JuliePelletier If I dont load helper how `echo base_url()` this works?

Comment: @wolfgang1983. No there are not anything doubled in autoload.php. This is working fine in local

Comment: Have you made sure controllers and models have first letter only upper case on class and filename.

Comment: Yes. This is ok. It was worked in another live server. Only not returing right value for base_url in this server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. It was a old project & there were a directory name `production` in `config` folder. I was forgot about this directory & there were not set the `base_url` this is why its auto detecting server IP.

In fact my config.php was not active here. Rather `production/config.php` was working there. Now solved

Answer (score 1):

Before using base_url() function load 'url' helper first in application/config/autoload.php

$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Or, manually using $this->load->helper('url');
Now echo base_url(); gives the url what have loaded in $config['base_url'] config parameter.