# Jquery Library inclusion in the header tag shows an error and Javascript functionalities do not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have included the following script in the header file.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js.js" ></script>
    </head>
```

And an error is thrown.

Is there anything I have to change?

Comment: can you explain what error you are getting?

Comment: But what was the error?

Comment: Append the error to the post, please.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are loading URL Helper, if not try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

and change these line

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js.js" ></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css.css">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js.js");?>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css.css");?>">
```

Comment: How did you figure out OP uses Codeignitor?

Comment: base_url function belongs to CI

Comment: Not necessarily, you can have such function without frameworks.

Comment: yes agreed, but mostly this kind of loading assets file is done when you are using CI