# Base_url not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just  a simple quetsion?

How to make CI

```
<?= base_url();?>
```

working with 'String'

The full codes as follows:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['admin'] == 1||$_SESSION['admin']== 0){
    echo "<a class='btn-common' href='<?= base_url();?>usr/logout'>LOGOUT</a>";
      }
      else{
          echo "<a class='btn-common2'></a>";
      }
```

Base_url is not woking

```
<?base_url();?>
```

Comment: First of all i don't understand this `<?=` . Secondly, it's better to always start with `<?php` and not `<?` . Lastly, you will have to use `echo`

Comment: `<?=` is like `<?php echo` and is valid syntax. No need to use echo using it!

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos `<?=` is a shorhand for `<?php echo ...` and its very common and valid

Comment: @leo_ap Thanks, great information to know!

Comment: Make sure you're loading the 'url' helper and it's set in the config. [Also everything else in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449396/3585500).

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos It's great for reducing bytes eaten by your codes. Why using many characters while you can just make it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a php method inside this string, you need to concatenate the string with the result instead:

```
    echo "<a class='btn-common' href='" . base_url() . "usr/logout'>LOGOUT</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks! It's work. Still newbie, racing for final web project

Answer (score 2):

Also like this. pass your path to `base_url()` as argument:

```
 <a class='btn-common' href='<?php echo base_url("usr/logout");?>'>LOGOUT</a>;
```

Don't forget to load `url` helper.using

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: In order to use PHP tags in the echo, he would need to close them before starting the tags

Comment: I'm not telling one way is better than the other, but in his case as he was using `echo` he already was in the php tags. For your example to work, he would need to replace the echo with `?>` and start a new php tag after printing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the string.

```
 echo "<a class='btn-common' href='".site_url('usr/logout')."'>LOGOUT</a>";
```

I would recommend to use site_url with your controller in parameter (which will use your config file to build url automatically).
With Codeigniter, you can use $this->session->userdata('admin') for retrieving session data too.

```
  if($this->session->userdata('admin')===1 || $this->session->userdata('admin')===0){
      echo "<a class='btn-common' href='".site_url('usr/logout')."'>LOGOUT</a>";
  }else{
      echo "<a class='btn-common2'></a>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using codeigniter links

```
<?php echo anchor("usr/logout",'Logout', 'title="Logout"');?>
```

You dont need to use base url, Codeigniter enters that for you