# CSS and pictures not loading in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Everything that is written with `base_url()` is not loading in Codeigniter.

```html
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>other/css/admin/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```html
<img class="brand" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>other/img/logo.png">
```

There are in:

> wamp -> www -> other -> css/img

My base_url is:

```html
$base_url = 'http://localhost/';
```

Comment: what is your `base_url`?

Comment: Do  you [know](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449396/3898339)  how to use `base_url()`

Comment: Of course, i do. See the examples above.

Comment: Make sure your css and stuff in root directory and your base url should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';` not `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';` on application/config/config,php

Answer (score 0):

Change your base url to this:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/PROJECTNAME/';
```

Here "PROJECTNAME" is your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change your base_url variable like this:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/other/';
```

where "other" is the project folder

Answer (score 0):

Change your base url to this:

```
$base_url = '/';
```