# bootstrap styles not work with code igniter

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

bootstrap folder was placed in root folder. styles were loaded in header sections of view files like this. but it's not worked. please help to solve this.

```
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/mystylesheet.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>        
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    <title>::CMSys || Add Division::</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Try with `<?php echo site_url();?>`

Comment: According this question to use `base_url` in `codeigniter` , you must load `url` helper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot `type="text/css"`

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/mystylesheet.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Make sure you have set your base url in the application config.php

> **Make sure you have the bootstrap folder out side of the application
>   folder.**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Or something like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/';
```

And autoload the url helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

If not place it in the construct area of controller. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

And make sure you have named your classes and filenames correct as explained here

1. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming
2. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

You may need a htaccess file in the main directory try some of these https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in "$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/'; ". then, styles worked. thank you for your guidance.