# CSS styles are not being applied in header

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have a  `header.php` file that I want to include in  a CodeIgniter view. The header is shown but the problem is that the CSS styles that I have written inside the `header.php` file are not applied and I don't understand why.
This is my header:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body >
<style>

.nav.navbar-nav li a{
color: #3232ff;
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a> 
</li>

  <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Log out</a>
</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**P.S** The weird thing is, if I include the css as inline styling , it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter

Comment: That's not my case

Comment: Your code is working fine, try changing the color and you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lubep1c6/

Comment: I changed the color, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Check you do not have an odd character in front of the hex color definition. Use Element Inspector to see what CSS is actually being applied.

Comment: @BenM  I tried this:  <li><a href="#" style="color:#3232ff;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a> 
</li> and the color is changed. So, the hex color definition is fine.

Comment: Yes I know, but have you actually checked in element inspector?

Comment: The specificity of the bootstrap css is too strong for you. Use !important

Comment: @BrianGottier Thanks, it works now

Comment: **Do not use `!important`**! Write a more specific selector!

Comment: You forgot `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specificity of the bootstrap style forces you to use important:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
ul.navbar-nav li a {
    color: red !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Do not use `!important`**! Write a more specific selector!

Comment: BenM, I believe bootstrap is already using !important for this style. This is bootstrap 3, but bootstrap 4 is doing it too. I don't think that writing a more specific selector can work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it wrong, You should remove the dot before the nav, that way you select the element. 
This is working and I've tested:

```
nav .navbar-nav li a{
color: #3232ff !importan;
}
```

This way you are referring to a .nav-bar class in a nav element. 
See result here:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body >
<style>
nav .navbar-nav li a{
color: #000000 !important;

}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a>
</li>

  <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Log out</a>
</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, check out `.navbar-nav`, the selector is correct.