# what is the different <?php echo base_url().'index.php/login/auth'?> with <?php echo base_url();?>/login/auth"> method="post">

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I had a problem with this

```
<?php echo base_url().'index.php/login/auth'?>" method="post">
```

and with this

```
<?php echo base_url();?>/login/auth"> method="post">
```

when I've trying to figure it out about the differences but stuck. please help me

Comment: You need to explain what your 'problem' actually is.  You are also providing a snippet of code without the portion that comes before it, and gives it context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd one is invalid due to the duplicate html end tag.  It should be:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>/login/auth" method="post">
```

If what you are saying is that the base_url() function is not returning a string, then [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter/6449396).

Comment: You mean an extra `>`?  There's only one `?>`.

Comment: @Devon, seems like either I misread it, or the question was editted, but either way good catch.

Comment: Yes, the point was I thought it was a ?> but regardless it appears to be part of a form tag.

Comment: it's a function. the 1st one its work but I want to change it to <?php echo base_url();?>/login/auth" method="post"> but it doesn't work... anyway I'm just starting learn php codeigniter things about 2 weeks for a campus task :D

Comment: @ChickenNanas Please edit, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51235363/edit, your question and add more details. Also please include the rendered results.

Comment: @user3783243 Look at the original and look at the version I posted.  You can see that he has `/login/auth>` method="post".  Invalid html.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread Devon comment, and then your follow up was the inverse of what I read. I'll remove my comments. @ChickenNanas If this resolves your issue you should accept the answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not you should update the question to be clearer, or post your answer.