# How to put https correctly on links that are in another location?

Tags: codeigniter, https

I am facing the following problem in my hosting with https

[image]

How should I put https in my tags?

```
 <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
<link href="<?= base_url() ?>public/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Waves Effect Css -->
<link href="<?= base_url() ?>public/plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Animation Css -->
<link href="<?= base_url() ?>public/plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Materialize Css -->
<link href="<?= base_url() ?>public/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom Css -->
<link href="<?= base_url() ?>public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or error messages.  Paste the actual text instead.

Comment: I corrected the question

Comment: Well, you half-corrected it, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer over here might be of value to you: [base_url() function not working in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449396/6838396).

The important part in question:

> Remember also that the value returned is the site's base url as provided in the config file. CodeIgniter will accomodate an empty value in the config file as well:
>
> > If this (base_url) is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and path to your installation.
>
> **application/config/config.php, line 13**

In other words, you probably just want to set the configuration variable to the correct value (using 'https'). You can probably even tell it to use [$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php) to toggle between http and https appropriately.