# How to get base url in pre_controller hook in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on hook file, i am using `pre_controller` function of hook, but when i tried to use `base_url()` function in it, it is not working for me, it give me this error `Call to undefined function base_url()`, can anyone please help me to resolve this error ? here i have added my whole function

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = function()
{
    $this->CI = get_instance();
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $router =& load_class('Router', 'core','uri','url');
    $controller_name = $router->fetch_class();  
    $action_name = $router->fetch_method();  
    $segement = $router->uri->segment(2);
    echo base_url(); die;
    try {   
        $rc = new ReflectionClass($controller_name);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        if($segement == "") {
            echo base_url(); die;
            //header("Location:".$controller_name.'/overview');
            //redirect($controller_name.'/overview');
            //exit;
        }
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because `base_url()` gets initialized if a Controller is loaded.
And `pre_controller` basically means the opposite.

There are two options for you

**Option 1**

create a PreControllerHook.php in your `application/hooks/` directory.

```
class PreControllerHook extends CI_Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $controller_name = $this->router->fetch_class();  
        //... and so on
    }
}
```

Setup your `hooks.php` config

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = [
    [
        'class' => 'PreControllerHook',
        'function' => 'initialize',
        'filename' => 'PreControllerHook.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
    [
];
```

**Option 2**

create a PostControllerConstructorHook.php in your `application/hooks/` directory.

```
class PostControllerConstructorHook
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $ci = get_instance();
        $controller_name = $ci->router->fetch_class();  
        //... and so on
    }
}
```

Setup your `hooks.php` config

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = [
    [
        'class' => 'PostControllerConstructorHook',
        'function' => 'initialize',
        'filename' => 'PostControllerConstructorHook.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
    [
];
```

> You can find more information on their official documentation page [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html).

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work for you

[base_url() function not working in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)