# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function base_url()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to setup it for the firs time, but it give the following error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function base_url() in /home/u6256344/public_html/skripsiindah.online/login.php:51 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u6256344/public_html/skripsiindah.online/login.php on line 51

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = anti_injection($_POST['username']);
    $password = anti_injection(md5($_POST['password']));

    // menghindari sql injection
    $injeksi_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
    $injeksi_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);

    if (!ctype_alnum($injeksi_username) OR !ctype_alnum($injeksi_password)){
        header("Location:".base_url()."/404");
    }else{
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $login  = $conn->query($query);
        $verify = $login->num_rows;
    $v      = $login->fetch_array();
```

Comment: What is `anti_injection`?

Comment: PHP doesn't have a `base_url` function.

Comment: The warning is clear enough, function `base_url` doesn't exists. Did you define this function in another file and the forgot to include that file? Did you copy this piece of code from somewhere on the internet?

Comment: I did find this: [base_url() function not working in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449396/3986005) As adviced by others: Do not use this code in a production environment, it isn't safe.

Comment: @Dharman im only hosting my friend source code. in localhost its good but when its hosting its show error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `base_url()`, user `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`.

It returns the current url, but only the path part.

[For a guide on $_SERVER variables.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)