# codeigniter base_url is not updating in XAMPP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on the Codeigniter project, I downloaded the code from the server to work on locally (XAMPP server) but when I try to change the `base_url()`, it is not even updating.
like here:

```
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';

/*
```

but when I open the project in Browser:

`<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>login_alert/login_verify_alert/>`

it returns the old `base_url()` and redirects the project to the server.

`<form action="https://project.com/app/login_alert/login_verify_alert//" method="POST" class="md-float-material form-material">`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

update `$autoload['helper'] = array('url')`

[base_url() function not working in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your local server is caching the previous page, you can append
`?t=RANDOM__NUMBER`
to the URL to force it to produce an uncached version of the page.
Example:

```
https://project.com/app/login_alert/login_verify_alert?t=231231
```

Or use inspect tools and check 'Disable Cache'.

Secondly you should use site_url() when referencing controllers, base_url is generally for file system functions such as loading a CSS file, or JS file.